# preciso de ajudar para calcular o fatorial em ordem crescente e decrescente em uma equação!

Tags: c, for, fatorial

preciso resolver essa questao: 
Faça um programa que leia o número de termos e um valor positivo para X. Calcule e mostre o valor
da série a seguir:
 * 
S = (-X2/!1) (+X3/2!) (–X4/3!) (+X5/4!) (-X6/3!) (+X7/2!) (-X8/1!) (+X9/2!) (-X10/3!) (+X11/4!) -...

não tenho ideia de como fazer para o fatorial ir aumentando e diminuindo dessa forma. Comecei fazendo esse código:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < termos; i++) {
    if (expoente % 2 == 0) { //se o expoente for par, x é negativo...
      x = -x;
    }

    fatorial = calcFat(numFat); //calcula o fatorial do numero...
    expoente++;
  }
```

Assim eu calculo item por item, mas o que falta é apenas fazer o numFat ciclar de 1 a 4 e depois de 4 a 1.

ps: Função criada para calcular o fatorial:

```
int calcFat(int num) { //calcula o fatorial e retorna seu valor...
  int resultado = num;
  for (int i = (num-1); i > 1; i--) {
    resultado  = resultado * i;
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Uma possibilidade é definir uma variável contador e um incremento com valor inicial. A cada ciclo some o incremento ao contador e se o contador for 1 ou 4 você inverte o sinal do incremento (incremento = - incremento;) da mesma forma que fez com a variável x.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: editei o código da pergunta colocando alguns espaços...deixar tudo grudado, sem espaços, fica mais difícil ainda de entender...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui de uma forma não tão prática porém funcional e resolveu meu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
 * Faça um programa que leia o número de termos e um valor positivo para X. Calcule e mostre o valor
da série a seguir:
 * 
S = -X2 +X3 –X4 +X5 -X6 +X7 -X8 +X9 -X10 +X11 -...
          1!     2!      3!       4!     3!     2!    1!       2!        3!       4!
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int termos, x, expoente =2, numFat = 1, fatorial;
    float resp;

    printf("Insira o numero de termos: ");
    scanf("%d", &termos);
    printf("Insira o valor de x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(int i = 0; i < termos; i++){

        if(numFat == 4){
            while(1==1){
                 if(expoente % 2 == 0){//se o expoente for par, x é negativo...
                  x = -x;
                  }

                fatorial = calcFat(numFat);//calcula o fatorial do numero...
                resp = resp +((float) powf(x, expoente) / fatorial);
                numFat--;
                expoente++;
                if(i == termos){
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                if(numFat == 1)
                    break;
            }
        }else if(numFat == 1){
            while(1 ==1){

                if(expoente % 2 == 0){//se o expoente for par, x é negativo...
                     x = -x;
                }else if(expoente % 2 != 0){
                    x = fabs(x);
                }

                fatorial = calcFat(numFat);
                resp = resp + ((float)powf(x, expoente) / fatorial);
                numFat++;
                expoente++;
                if(i == termos){
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                if(numFat == 4)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Valor da sequencia: %.2f", resp);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int calcFat(int num){//calcula o fatorial e retorna seu valor...
    int resultado = num;
    for(int i = (num-1); i > 1; i--){
        resultado  = resultado * i;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução otimizada, aproveitando os detalhes da definição do problema: o valor de x alterna de - para +, o expoente começa com 2 e vai crescendo, a tabeça de fatoriais é fixa.

```
#include <math.h>    // pow
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // abs

static int fact(int n)
{
  int i, result = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= n;i++)
    result *= i;
  return result;
}

static int facts[6];

static void initFacts()
{
  facts[0] = fact(1);
  facts[1] = fact(2);
  facts[2] = fact(3);
  facts[3] = fact(4);
  facts[4] = facts[2];
  facts[5] = facts[1];
}

int main()
{
  int i, nTermos, x;
  double exp = 2, result = 0;

  int j = 0; // para indexar facts

  initFacts();

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* numero de termos: ");
  scanf("%d", &nTermos);
  printf("* valor de x: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("*\n");

  x = abs(x); // garante que x comeca positivo

  for (i = 0; i < nTermos; i++, exp++)
  {
    x = -x;
    result += pow(x, exp) / facts[j++];
    if (j == 6)
      j = 0;
  }

  printf("* result=%lf\n", result);
  printf("*");
}
```

Comment: Não sei o porque, mas o resultado feito com uma calculadora não bate com seu código. Contudo seu código irá me ajudar a otimizar o meu. Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: pode ser que tenha algum errinho, eu realmente não verifiquei muito bem, mas o objetivo era esse mesmo: mostrar que é possível escrever uma versão mais simples de entender e bastante otimizada, em relação à sua solução

Comment: hmm, olhando de novo, tinha esquecido de incrementar o expoente

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela ajuda! estou fazendo alguns exercícios do project euler, e futuramente começarei a otimizar meus algoritmos. Sua lógica me ajudará muito nesse caminho!